# Threading wxPython GUI?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, wxpython, nonblocking

I've tried as many combination of threading  as I know.

(wxPython "Frame1" created using wxFormBuilder)

This seems like it should work but it just crashes:

```
import wx
import wx.richtext
import time
import threading

class MyFrame1 ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer3 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_staticText1 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"This is a Thingy", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_staticText1.Wrap( -1 )
        bSizer3.Add( self.m_staticText1, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

        self.m_richText1 = wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0|wx.VSCROLL|wx.HSCROLL|wx.NO_BORDER|wx.WANTS_CHARS )
        bSizer3.Add( self.m_richText1, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_button2 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"MyButton", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer3.Add( self.m_button2, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

        self.SetSizer( bSizer3 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass

class Main(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        app = wx.App()
        frame = MyFrame1(None)
        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print "Starting Thread!"
    t = Main()
    t.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    print "This should print while the window is open!"
```

Crash Dialog:

```
Python quit unexpectedly while using the libwx_osx_cocoau-3.0.0.1.0.dylib plug-in.
```

I've looked through numerous threads, read the ["Non-Blocking Gui documentation"](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Non-Blocking%20Gui). It's not clicking for me.

Answer (score 2):

OSX requires that the GUI remain in the main thread.

Comment: So the only option is to spawn my "worker" threads in the background before I call the MainLoop?

Comment: You can create and start the worker threads at any time.  You just need to keep the creation, modification, etc. of UI objects and the running of the MainLoop in the main thread.